# Caps on tactile switch

Tags: switches

I know that caps do exist for 12x12mm tactile switches:

[image]

and such caps are very standard, we can find a lot.

But **is it possible to fit caps on 6x6 mm or 8x8mm or 10x10mm tactile switches**? (not sure if 8x8 or 10x10mm are common or not)

*I'm not looking for shopping advice (I know how to order by a supplier), but to know if it's common or not to see caps on such small switches.*

[image]

Comment: I would avoid using the term "caps"...Anyone know of a better word?

Comment: I was sure it's about filtering the switch bouncing

Comment: @Bort Isn't "cap" the right word? (I'm not native english speaker).

Comment: @GregoryKornblum What do you mean by switch bouncing?

Comment: @Basj - "Cap" is short for "capacitor", so it causes confusion.

Comment: The answer is: Ask the supplier and this has nothing to do with circuits

Answer (score 2):

Yes!! You can get 6x6 mm tact switches that can have a button cap snapped on. Here is one example: E-Switch TL3301SPF260QG

[image]

The key is to look for parts that have the square actuator. This keeps a button cap oriented in the correct direction and the post feature of the actuator allows the cap to snap on and stay on. I have used this type multiple times on projects but also find that right angle versions work nicely when the switches must protrude through a front panel that is next to the circuit board.

The right angle type that I have used (E-Switch TL1105JAF250Q) look like this. Through hole is used so that there is a rugged switch mounting and good alignment of the button to holes in the front panel. The caps I use for these are designed to fit through a square hole which are easily cut through a front panel made of aluminum with a laser cutting process.

[image]

Here is an example of one product I did that uses the right angle switches. They protrude through a front panel that is also covered with a die cut Lexan overlay. The design has the buttons protrude only enough so that the push and feel is just right. Not sticking out more than maybe about 40 mils or so.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Michael for your answer. To be more specific, is it possible to mount caps on 6x6mm switches like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nLaQ.jpg ?

Comment: Not really. The types of switch actuators that you showed are not really made to accommodate caps. Any attempt to do so would be a kludge at best as far as I can evaluate. That is why I showed 6x6mm type switch with the square post actuator. The part shown is an SMT type but there are equivalent through hole types as well. The caps snap on as they are designed to do and work very well. So I really do not understand why you are stuck on using the non-optimum component. You can use the longer round post actuator as a small knob by poking it through a panel but they can be hard on the fingers.

Comment: Thanks. I asked the question @Michael because I have a big number of such 6x6mm switches at home, and I was wondering if I could use them with caps, or if I should buy new ones. Now I see I should better buy new ones. (Any cheap standard reference that is available by Farnell? Just in case you already know one)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is quite old, but I was looking for some information and guidance myself, and came across this post.

There are caps for 6mmx6mm switches that the OP posted about, as far as I can tell.

Here is one such example - [https://www.amazon.com/uxcell-Shaped-Tactile-Button-Protector/dp/B078RH6HLM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B078RH6HLM)

[image: uxcell-Shaped-Tactile-Button-Protector]

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I faced exactly this problem and had a company in China mould them for me in silicone.  The cost is higher than for an off-the-shelf product but not prohibitive - about $1 each for the first 1000 parts.

Comment: Did you manage to eliminate the squishiness of the buttons when there's silicone rubber between the switch and the user? That is, to keep a good feeling when operating the button.

Comment: If you have a low operating force (70g) and hard compound (80 Shore A) it’s fine.