# Switch button caps leeway

Tags: switches, button

In relation to the answer at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/298969/35737, namely when the switch buttons needs to protrude through the casing. I do not have special equipment for precision cutouts in the said casing. Is there any way for me to easily match the cutout with the protruding tactile switch button?

Comment: You can buy button caps and bezels (matching) that require less precision in the drilling of your casing/front-plate

Comment: @Andyaka any such examples ? There are hundreds of such things on any big vendor's site.

Comment: That would make this a product recommendation question, which would be off-topic here.

Comment: Then maybe some keywords for those leeway parts.